# question about locale

Tags: iphone, locale

```
NSLocale *curentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSString *locale = [curentLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier 
                                             value:[curentLocale localeIdentifier]];
NSLog(@"locale = %@",locale);
```

I'm getting on console locale = English (India) .this  comes because my device is from india.
if i take the country with maximum character  and  language with maximum character, then how much characters  a locale  can have? this is my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]` to get an NSArray with all available locale identifiers. Then loop through the array and search for the one with the most characters.

I'd be careful with this, though, and cater for longer strings, because I would imagine that the list of available locales could change in the future.